# Trying to use libsodium with web worker error TypeError: sodium.crypto_pwhash is not a function

Tags: web-worker, libsodium

I imported sodium.js using importScripts, but when web worker runs it gives error TypeError: sodium.crypto_pwhash is not a function. Console.log sodium.js in worker however prints the sodium object. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this issue](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js/issues/63), you need to load the [browser-sumo version](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js#standard-vs-sumo-version) so it includes `crypto_pwhash`.

```js
const worker_script = `
  self.sodium = {
    onload: function (sodium) {
     postMessage( sodium.crypto_pwhash.toString() );
    }
  };
  importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jedisct1/libsodium.js@master/dist/browsers-sumo/sodium.js');
`;
const worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ], { type: "text/javascript" } ) ) );
worker.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log( data );
```